# Python: Doing MNLogit, outputs only show 6 of the 7 classes of the target variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

There are 7 classes (3,4,5,6,7,8,9) of the target variable (‘quality’). It is only showing up 1-6 after encoding or 4-9 without encoding. Am I missing something??

```
reduced_data = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';')
reduced_data[['quality']] = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(reduced_data[['quality']].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
reduced_data.dropna()

model_1 = reduced_data.drop(columns=['fixed acidity','volatile acidity','citric acid',
                                  'residual sugar','pH','free sulfur dioxide','total sulfur dioxide','sulphates']


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(model_1.drop(columns=['quality']), model_1['quality'],
                                                    test_size=0.25, random_state=2)

X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
X_test = sm.add_constant(X_test)

model_reduced = sm.MNLogit(Y_train, X_train)

results_reduced = model_reduced.fit()

print(results_reduced.summary())
```

Comment: Please include explicitly your imports and use the appropriate tags; one should not need to dig in the code to see that you are using `statsmodels`

Comment: duplicate, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662278/why-mnlogit-returns-classes-num-1-params-and-how-get-them-all